# Generic types - Name can be simplified

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I have below two statements.

```
Task<List<int>> taskWithInLineAction = new Task<List<int>>(() =>
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        ints.Add(i);
    }
    return ints;
});

Task<List<int>> taskWithFactoryAndState = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>((stateObj) =>
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)stateObj; i++)
    {
        ints.Add(i);
    }
    return ints;
}, 2000);
```

Vs2015 warns me that

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>((stateObj)
```

can be simplified to

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((stateObj)
```

As I can see I can even use it without any type and VS infers generic type from lambda expression return value type, as below:

```
Task taskWithFactoryAndState = Task.Factory.StartNew((stateObj) =>
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)stateObj; i++)
    {
        ints.Add(i);
    }
    return ints;
}, 2000);
```

But this is not applicable to the first statement. In this case, VS force me to include generic types.

Could you please help me, why these two behaves differently?

[image]

Comment: Because you must always provide generic arguments to constructors. The same doesn't apply to methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two code samples do different things. Easiest way to see this is to put a break-point in the function of both parts and to press F5. It will hit the break-point of the second part even though it is below the first.

Now for the explanation:

The first one is just **creating a generic object** and when calling the constructor you **must explicitly say** what type you are creating.

```
Task<List<int>> taskWithInLineAction = new Task<List<int>>(() =>
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        ints.Add(i);
    }
    return ints;
});
```

So when you write `new ...` you must specify what type.

However, in the second section you are **executing a function** which returns an object and you are assigning it to a variable.

```
Task<List<int>> taskWithFactoryAndState = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>((stateObj) =>
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)stateObj; i++)
    {
        ints.Add(i);
    }
    return ints;
}, 2000);
```

At this point the task has already been executed and is running in the background. Because you are not directly instantiating the object visual studio tells you that the return type can be inferred and therefore "name can be simplified".

*If you look visual studio also says you can `await` it while it doesn't say that to the first section:*

```
List<int> taskWithFactoryAndState = await Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>((stateObj) =>
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)stateObj; i++)
    {
        ints.Add(i);
    }
    return ints;
}, 2000);
```

Comment: @Omer K - Did this help you understand the issue?

Answer (score 3):

**Simple design perspective:**

- If an object is initialized using `Generic Constructor`, then type needs to be mandatory supplied and that's what flows to the parameters, which they need to strictly adhere
- If an Object is initialized using `Generic Method`, then type may be defined using the method Output, and that needs to be adhered by the Type returned.

Thus the role reversal in the two cases defined above

**Case 1: Using Generic Constructor**

Initialization is done using `Task` class constructor, since we are using the generic version, therefore `Task<T>` constructor, check out the various options on the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx). Important point remains that `Task<TResult>` type is taking parameter as `Func` delegate with `TResult` as Output, where type of Output is mapped using the `Task<TResult>`, that's why its mandatory to define the type for Task class, during initialization, its not the other way round. It is not possible to use a `Func` delegate as parameter, whose return type is not `TResult` (by design), thus enforcing the strict type check. Constructor used in this case is  following.

`Task<TResult>(Func<TResult>)`

**Case 2: Using Generic Method**

In this case `Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult>(Func<TResult>)` method is used to create a `Task` object, where the return type of the `Task` is managed by the `Func` delegate and its return type, thus the type checking is still enforced but its opposite to the first case, therefore Task returned should have the same type as the `Func` delegate, check the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321455(v=vs.110).aspx)

In case of Visual studio its able to pick up the nuance details from the compiler, which it runs on every modification and can suggest, whether change is optional / mandatory and accordingly user is prompted for an action and thus graying out the optional code